# TFS 2018 tree query

Tags: tfs, tree

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VY9Bc.png

How do I edit this query to INclude children items that are completed?

Comment: What's that mean for the `completed` here? including closed?

Comment: There's a TFS state "Completed"

Comment: Do you mean you want to query the completed children items?

Comment: If the parent or grandparent is still active, then I want all the children (completed and not completed)

Comment: If I didn't misunderstand your question, the query in your screenshot should work.

Comment: The query in my screenshot returns all active parents/grandparents, but only children that are NOT completed … and I want ALL children, regardless of state